# Was my username vulgar?

Tags: discussion, support, display-names

My username has been changed to default without any notice. The original username was "AshWhole"

Yes, it is similar to an *inappropriate* word, but does not the exact spelling, nor the pronounciation. Also, the actual word isn't even used in context of sexuality nor am I targetting anyone.

I don't think it offends sentiments of anyone. I don't think it's vulgar. I did read the tons of already discussed question on "inappropriate usernames". And this username **Does not** come into that category , in my opinion.

I request to set it back to the original username.

Comment: I would suggest that, if you want to convince the mod team that your choice of that name is genuine and sincere, you stop presenting your opinion and present actual reasons for your choice of that name.  Perhaps you're a forestry expert or enthusiast (but then, WholeAsh would make more sense) or a carpenter, or whatever.  But failing to present reasons weakens your case.

Comment: @postmortes, I didn't expect it to be removed in the first place, this is the first time. The username just resembles something inappropriate(in formal context), but isn't just a cheap typo and has a different pronounciation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems you purposefully chose a word that is similar to what according to you is an  *inappropriate* word.

It is not very clear why you even need to ask why this was changed. Basically you tried to place the name right  next to the line of what is inappropriate but just to the appropriate side in your opinion.

This is like somebody that puts their finger right in-front of the eye of somebody and says "You can't complain. I am not even touching you."

This type of behavior is not appreciated on the site. It often goes under the radar, but in this case is was noted and acted on.

Comment: I use that alias everywhere, how I came up with that name(back story) would be irrelevant here, one reason is The username is just intended to be "funny" (since the *actual* word means je*k).Your analogy involves invading someone's personal space, while it is *my* username directed to *me*. Do I say anything rude? On one of such discussion someone argued that others use your username to refer to you, and that'd be against SE CoC. But you can't classify this username as exactly profane(and hence against CoC for others) and if I set that name myself which is not harming anyone.

Comment: Besides, is this only considered profane because it looks close to *inappropriate*? My profile picture is far more profane, you just can't see it from the surface. What if I use another language in my name or another connotation or something like this-ɐsɥʍɥo˥ǝ?

Comment: It strikes me as playing games, @user675453, and not playing in good faith.  This is a site dedicated to mathematics, not to host users who want to suggest offensive language, without *literally*, letter for letter, using it.

Comment: @amWhy, Good faith? And what's wrong with that if doesn't harm anyone or is purposefully rude/offensive?

Comment: Yes, though I wrote "good faith", which I think is absent in your chosen username and this post.  This site is named [mathematics.se], not *How to be purposefully rude through ones username, and still claim innocence.*

Comment: @amWhy, I don't understand what you mean by that(good faith)

Comment: If I intended to be rude, I would have used "Ur" in the beginning, which I do not. It is my username and it conventionally refers to me

Comment: @user675453 It is visibly clear to you that this user name could be seen as problematic and why. It is also not particularly original even. You can chose a user name that does not cause issues or none at all. You can also stop using the site altogether.  What will not happen is that we engage in a prolonged debate about this. If you have any further question related to this contact SE directly under "contact us."

Comment: @quid, I was(am) disappointed that is was removed without any notice whatsoever and that I did not get get a reply from SE (in 24 hours). I don't want a debate either. Inconclusive and Already too many. And well, you can't say if it's original or not. Some people come late in this world. A shift cipher won't be "visually problematic", would it?

Comment: @user675453 not sure what you mean exactly, if you do a ROT13 on it likely that would pass. For the removal without notice  and the non-reply, sorry about that. Likely people are short on time and it did not seem like something major and particularly it seemed self-explanatory, which indeed it was.

Comment: I suppose, a basic circular shift may arrive questions again, and isn't really interesting. How about UmbQbify _Key20_.

Comment: @user675453 Personally I will not object to the the username "UmbQbify Key20"  (especially if I am allowed to call you Umb and you don't insist that I spell it out; yet then with autocomplete it is usually a non issue) And I'd be surprised anyone would have objected to that. Now  I suppose given the context users can find out and know, but likely it'll still pass.

Comment: Alright, thanks.